# Why do I see jerky animation when using this UIView animation block?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, core-animation

I have a a tab bar that is made in the application delegate. By calling an action form a button click from one of the views loaded from the tab bar, I open the help screen but there is a jerking motion after loading.

forgive me for speaking informally..I have been picking my brain for the past few hours trying to figure this out..

```
-(void)flipToHelp {
 HelpViewController *helpVariable = [[HelpViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HelpView" bundle:nil];
 [self setHelpViewController:helpVariable];
 [UIView beginAnimations:@"flipview" context:nil]; 
 [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
 [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
 [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft
 forView:_window cache:YES];

[_window removeFromSuperview];
[helpVariable release];
self.window.rootViewController = self.HelpViewController;
[UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling `[_window removeFromSuperview]`?  Shouldn't you be removing the tab bar controller from the window instead?

Comment: I tried that but I keep getting an error using "self.window = self.HelpViewController;" ...warning: Semantic Issue: Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'UIWindow *' from 'HelpViewController *'

Comment: I'm not sure if reassigning the rootViewController changes the view.  If so, all you need to do is delete the `[_window removeFromSuperview]` line.  If changing rootViewController is not enough, you can do: `[self.tabBarController removeFromSuperview]; [self.window addSubview:self.HelpViewController.view];`.

Comment: WOAH! removing `[_window removeFromSuperview];` and adding `[self.window addSubview:self.HelpViewController.view];` did the trick! I was unable to add `[self.tabBarController removeFromSuperview];`   To bring the main screen back I did this     `[self.HelpViewController.view setHidden:1];
    [self.HelpViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  [UIView commitAnimations];}` It seems to be working but is it the right way to do it? Thanks so much Daniel!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to reiterate from the comment thread, you shouldn't be removing the window from its superview (it doesn't technically have a superview, so it's probably causing problems).  <s>And setting the window's `rootViewController` property should swap out the view hierarchies,</s> Apparently the jerkiness comes from changing the window's `rootViewController` property, so maybe the solution is to avoid using that property.  Here's what I think should be enough to accomplish this:

```
-(void)flipToHelp {
     HelpViewController *helpVariable = [[HelpViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HelpView" bundle:nil];
     [UIView beginAnimations:@"flipview" context:nil]; 
     [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
     [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:_window cache:YES];
    [self.tabBarController removeFromSuperview];
    [_window addSubview:helpVariable];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: no jerking here `-(void)flipToHelp {
    HelpViewController *helpVariable = [[HelpViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HelpView" bundle:nil];
    [self setHelpViewController:helpVariable];
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"flipview" context:nil]; 
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown
                           forView:_window cache:YES];
    [helpVariable release];    
    [self.window addSubview:self.HelpViewController.view];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}`

Comment: Maybe the jerkiness is a problem with how UIWindow updates the views when you set `rootViewController`.  Maybe your best bet is to not use that property at all -- I'll update the answer with your solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)flipToHelp {
  HelpViewController *helpVariable = [[HelpViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HelpView" bundle:nil];
  [self setHelpViewController:helpVariable];
  [helpVariable release];

  [UIView beginAnimations:@"flipview" context:nil]; 
  [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
  [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
  [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft
                         forView:self.window
                           cache:YES];

  self.window.rootViewController = self.HelpViewController;
  [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

How about this code? Does it still have a jerky animation?